# Different treatment of division by 0 in Delphi 10.3 VCL and FMX applications

Tags: delphi, exception, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

The command a: = 1/0; leads to different results:

VCL - WIN32: floating point divide by zero

VCL - WIN64: FLOAT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO

FMX - Win32, Win64, Android: no exception, a = 0

Is that intentional?

Comment: The compiler and the RTL are the same regardless of which UI framework you use. So I would expect consistent results whether you use VCL or FMX. Unless there is some low-level hook that VCL is using that FMX is not, or vice versa

Comment: Please check what System.Math.GetExceptionMask()` returns in each case. and add that to your question. Look at `System.Math.TArithmeticExceptionMask`for definition.

Comment: Also look at both answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47611635/2292722)

Comment: That seems implausible. On Windows compilers that code assigns +inf to a.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg: VCL
 
TArithmeticExceptionMask = 50 = exDenormalized exUnderflow exPrecision  
 
a := 1/0;   raises exception and enters EXCEPT  

FMX 
 
TArithmeticExceptionMask = 63 = exInvalidOp exDenormalized exZeroDivide exOverflow exUnderflow exPrecision 
 
a := 1/0;   dont't raises exception and does not enter EXCEPT

Comment: @Remy Lebeau & David Heffernan: I also tested with a := b / c;  Where c = 0. The results are the same as a := 1/0 like on top of this question. I looked at the question mentioned from Tom Brunberg. I think the treatment of division by zero should be the same in VCL and FMX and on all platforms.