# How to get Delphi side exception class from generic EDelphi exception in script

Tags: exception, delphi, dwscript

Calling a Delphi side function from a script that raises an exception raises a generic EDelphi exception on the script side. This hides the exception class of the actual Delphi side exception. I tried to investigate the implementation of the EDelphi Ijaddajadda interface but am lacking skills to see a way to extract the Delphi side class or at least the class name. The truth has to be out there...

Example, script side

```
Try
 MyDelphiSideFunction; // May raise EOutOfmemory
Except on E:Exception do
 PrintLn(E.ClassName);
End;
```

This always prints "EDelphi", no matter the actual Delphi side exception class (EOutOfmemory in this example).

How to get the "real" class or class name from E?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly get the exception class type as the DWScript exception handler doesn't store that information anywhere and the Delphi side type wouldn't make sense inside the script anyway. You can however easily get the class name from the `EDelphi` script side exception object via the `EDelphi.ExceptionClass` property. Like this:

### Script

```
try

  var x := 1/0;

except
  on E: EDelphi do
    WriteLn('Error: ' + E.Message + ' (' + E.ExceptionClass + ')');

  on E: Exception do
    WriteLn('Error: ' + E.Message);
else
  WriteLn('Unknown exception type');
end;
```

### Output

```
Error: Floating point division by zero (EZeroDivide)
```

You can see the DWScript source code that transforms a Delphi side exception to a script side `EDelphi` exception here:
https://github.com/EricGrange/DWScript/blob/2d61c8a95fb4a2aab328f3cc84bb9f243c927286/Source/dwsExprs.pas#L2244

### How I found the answer

I simply searched the source on Github (the search on the main Bitbucket repo sucks) for "EDelphi": https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AEricGrange%2FDWScript%20EDelphi&type=code

This gave me this piece of code:

```
// A Delphi exception. Transform it to a EDelphi-dws exception
exceptObj:=CreateEDelphiObj(mainException.ClassName, mainException.Message);
```

I then looked at the `CreateEDelphiObj` method:

```
function TdwsProgramExecution.CreateEDelphiObj(const ClassName : String;
                                   const Message : String) : IScriptObj;
begin
   Result := IScriptObj(IUnknown(
      ProgramInfo.Vars[SYS_EDELPHI].Method[SYS_TOBJECT_CREATE].Call([ClassName, Message]).Value));
   (Result.ExternalObject as TdwsExceptionContext).ReplaceTop(LastScriptError); // temporary constructor expression
end;
```

This looks like a call to a script side constructor, passing the `ClassName` and `Message` strings as parameters. That's fine, but what happens to the `ClassName` value?

Again, looking at the search result I noticed the Delphi side implementation of the [`EDelphi` constructor](https://github.com/EricGrange/DWScript/blob/2d61c8a95fb4a2aab328f3cc84bb9f243c927286/Source/dwsMethodExprs.pas#L353C1-L357C5):

```
procedure TDelphiExceptionCreateMethod.Execute(info : TProgramInfo; var ExternalObject: TObject);
begin
   inherited;
   Info.ValueAsVariant[SYS_EDELPHI_EXCEPTIONCLASS_FIELD]:=Info.ValueAsVariant['Cls']
end;
```

So the constructor calls the inherited constructor and then stores the `ClassName` value in the `FExceptionClass` (the value of the `SYS_EDELPHI_EXCEPTIONCLASS_FIELD` constant) field.

At this point I could guess that the property would be called `ExceptionClass` so I used my [DWScriptStudio](https://bitbucket.org/anders_melander/dwscriptstudio) IDE/debugger to write the example and verify the result.
[image: DWScriptStudio]

Comment: Many thanks @AndersMelander, this is exactly what I was searching for. But where on earth did you find the ExceptionClass property? I crawled through the DWS sources for hours for something like this. And even a full grep for ExceptionClass over all DWS sources did not reveal a meaningful hint to me. Would you mind to enlighten me?

Fun fact: DWS is perfectly happy with var x := 1/0, resolving for INF. Can this be changed to raise an exception instead?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how I found the `ExceptionClass` property. With regard to INF vs. an exception, it could be a difference in how our exception masks are set up, or it could be this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611635/delphi-berlin-10-1-division-by-zero-exception-missing

Comment: Wunderful explanation @AndersMelander. Really appreciate! And your DWScript Studio also is a great piece of work I'm currently having a look at. Am wondering how hard it would be to strip out that costly DevExpress.

Comment: Most of the DevExpress controls have corresponding equivalent VCL controls but a few don't (e.g the TcxTreeList). The ribbon can easily be replaced with something else since all the UI logic is delegated to actions. I think the hardest part will be the docking system. The VCL docking system is... problematic, at best.